# Timer for interrupts in operating systems

Tags: operating-system

Operating systems ensure that before turning over to user mode, it sets timer for interrupts.
**Now what does setting timer for interrupts actually mean??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every processor has the ability to set timers. When the timer goes off, it causes an interrupt. The operating system defines a table of interrupt handlers, including one for the CPU timer.

At some interval the timer will go off and invoke the timer interrupt handler. This is where the operating system does most of its house keeping. For example, this the place a compute-bound process gets interrupted to allow another process to execute for a while.

The mechanism for setting the timer varies among systems. It is usually done by setting kernel-mode only register values.

Comment: Can u please , please elaborate or explain in more detail about the example provided by you.Thanks.  @user3344003

Comment: Please kindly elaorate answer @user3344003